# Trap in linux script not capturing exit code

Tags: linux, bash

```
    testttt(){
    echo after trapp
    }
    test(){
    echo inside testcode
    exit 2
    }
    trap 'testttt' 2
    test
```

When i run the script i get output 
        **->inside testcode**
         But I was expecting
        **->inside testcode
       after trapp**
       Why isnt trap 'testttt' 2 capturing testttt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trap only executes if your script receives `SIGINT` (signal 2), not any time it exits with status 2.

Instead, you should trap `EXIT`, then test the exit status inside your handler.

```
testttt(){
    exit_status=$?
    if [[ $exit_status -eq 2 ]]; then
        echo after trapp
    fi
}
test(){
    echo inside testcode
    exit 2
}
trap 'testttt' EXIT
test
```

Comment: and if instead of EXIT if I put 0 is it the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Add to @chepner answer you can send interrupt to your running script this way:

```
   testttt(){
    echo after trapp
    }
    test(){
    echo inside testcode
    kill -s SIGINT $$
    }
    trap 'testttt' 2
    test
```

Where `$$` will have PID of your script.